# Change default route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my Rails 3.1 application i have a UsersController, which gives me /users URL.

But i need /u instead for all REST actions.

What is the best practice for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define the "path", in your case, modify routes.rb to

```
resources :users, :path => 'u'
```